# How to make pairs from Range?

Tags: grouping, d

I have got range `MySQLTablesRange`. It's consist data like:
`aa_1 aa_3 aa_2 bb_2 bb_1 bb_3`

I need to create pairs like:
`aa_1 bb_1`
`aa_2 bb_2`
`aa_3 bb_3`

`std.algorithm` have method [group](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#.group) that doing similar thing, but I do not know how to write it in code. I did:

`MySQLTablesRange.each!(a => a.split("_")[1].array.group.writeln);`

But it's wrong, because `group` works with array, but not with single element.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: After testing this - I realised it's not 'group' you want. But chunkBy. Updated the answer to reflect that.
https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#chunkBy

You have to tell chunkBy how to chunk the data...

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    .sort!((a,b) => a%2 > b%2)        // separate odds n evens
    .chunkBy!((a,b) => a%2 == b%2);   // chunk them so all evens are in one range, odds in another.
```

That will create two groups. One with odd numbers, one with evens.

In your case it looks like you'd group them on the text that comes after '_' in each element.

```
"aa_1 aa_2 aa_3 bb_1 bb_2 bb_3 cc_1"
    .split(" ")
    .sort!((a,b) => a[$-1].to!int < b[$-1].to!int) // sort it so _1's are together, _2s are together. etc
    .chunkBy!((a,b) => a[$-1] == b[$-1]) // chunk them so they're in they're own range
    .each!writeln;   // print each range

$ rdmd test.d
["aa_1", "bb_1", "cc_1"]
["aa_2", "bb_2"]
["aa_3", "bb_3"]
```

Ideally you'd get index of _ and compare after that...

Comment: And what will be if I would have not aa_1, but aa_123? Minus one from $ will get wrong result...

Comment: Yeah, which is why i mentioned for you to get the index of the '_' and compare after that. I can't write it all for you ;)